# Flask error when using url_for

Tags: python, flask

EDIT: Sorry for bothering you, I have figured this out.

I'm creating a template in flask and I have a list of last calculations done by template. What I want is to create button for each calculated record to download results.

My template looks like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css href= '../asserts/stylesheet.css'>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <title>Project Firefox</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">This will be content of my site</div>
    <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    <ul class='calcs'>
    {% for calc in calcs %}
      {% if calc.calculated %}
        <li><b>Calculation {{ calc.id }} </b>{{ calc.date }} {{ calc.time }} <button><a href= "{{ url_for('outputs', filename=calc.output_file) }}">Download</a></button> </li>
      {% else %}
        <li><b>Calculation {{ calc.id }} </b>{{ calc.date }} {{ calc.time }} calculations still in progress</li>
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
      <li>There have been no calculations so far.</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

And what I've got is an error like this: `BuildError: ('outputs', {'filename': u'topologia_wynik2.top'}, None)`

How can I work this out? output_file format is text.

Comment: Is is `outputs` the name of a view method or the name of an HTML file?

Comment: outputs is a name of folder when I store my topologia_wynik file.
In my app.py i have method like this:

`@app.route('/outputs/<filename>')
def calculated_record(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['OUTPUT_FOLDER'], filename)`

EDIT - Thank you, your question made me look at right direction, and now all works!

Comment: I don't think you can use `url_for` in that way. It allows you to use `static` to serve static files but otherwise that parameter should be the name of a method that brings you to an endpoint.